# Sturm boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having difficulty with the following question:
$$y''+ky=0$$
$$y(-\pi)=y(\pi)$$
$$y'(-\pi)=y'(\pi)$$

For each eigenvalue $k$, there correspond(s):

1. Only one eigenfunction
2. Two eigenfunction
3. Two linearly independent eigenfunctions.
4. Two orthogonal eigenfunctions.

If someone could help me, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is $k>0$, $k<0$ or $k=0$? Try checking the solutions of your diff. equation in the 3 different cases.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the case $k<0$: the case $k>0$ is studied analogously, with due modifications in the solutions (imaginary exponentials are needed). The case  $k=0$ is degenerate with class of solutions given by $y(x)=A$, for any constant $A$.

If $k<0$ then the most general solution to the given ODE is

$y(x)=A\exp(\omega x)+B\exp(-\omega x)$,

with $A,B$ constants and $\omega:=\sqrt{-k}$. Note that $\omega^2:=-k>0$.

The periodic conditions $y(-\pi)=y(\pi)$ and $y'(-\pi)=y'(\pi)$ are equivalent to the system of equations

$\beta(A+B)=0\cap \beta(A-B)=0$,

with $\beta=\sin(\pi\omega)$.

If $\beta\neq 0$, then we arrive at the trivial solution $y(x)=0$ as $A=B=0$ is the only solution of the above system.

If $\beta= 0$, i.e. $\sin(\pi\omega)=0 \Leftrightarrow  \pi\omega=2\pi r\Leftrightarrow \omega=2r \Leftrightarrow -k=4r^2$, for some $r\in \mathbb Z$, then the original problem has solution(s)

$y(x)=A\exp(2r x)+B\exp(-2r x)$.

With these information you could proceed to answer to your question.